# JavaScript: I'm unsure of what conditions to use in a while loop through nodes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Suppose I have a static array of nodes: `nodeArray[<h1>, <p>, <p>]`, each node has a large number of properties. One such property is `children`, this property's value is a HTMLCollection of the next child node.

**FOR EXAMPLE:**

if `<h1>This is a parent. <span>This is a child</span></h1>` was the first node in nodeArray, calling `console.log(nodeArray[0].children)` would log `HTMLCollection[span]`. The `<span>` node will have the  exact same structure as it's `<h1>` parent, with its own `children` property containing the value of further child nodes (in this case it would be an empty HTMLCollection as the `<span>` node has no further children).

**CONTEXT:**

The JavaScript is a chrome extension content script that collates selected text elements of a webpage into an array of nodes. This means I can never have certainty as to how many children nodes there will be for any given element selected because I have not written the HTML of the webpage. Subsequently, I will need to use a while loop if I would like to execute code on each child element.

This is where the issue lies - what condition(s) should I use in my while loop that allows me to loop until there are no more child elements left.

Comment: Seems to me you need something other than a while loop. Have you thought about using anything else?

Comment: I have no clue what you are asking....

Comment: [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like a recursive loop?

```
function doSomethingWithNodes(nodes, level)
{
  level = level || 1;

  nodes.forEach(function(node) {
    console.log('Level ' + level, node);

    if ('children' in node && Array.isArray(node.children))
      doSomethingWithNodes(node.children, level + 1);
  });
}

doSomethingWithNodes(nodeArray);
```

Comment: Had not even considered recursion, thought it was possible with a simple while loop, cheers.

Comment: Please accept an answer, then. Next time it’d be helpful if you could provide some code you’ve tried so people can help you better. 

Comment: Sorry mate im new here, will do so for following questions. Shall I edit my question to make it more clear?

Comment: Thx, now that you’ve found help I think there is no need to clarify the question further, but keep this in mind next time. Someone closed your question because "it needs more focus" – you can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Hi again, could you briefly give me some insight into the purpose of `if ('children' in node && Array.isArray(node.children))`? It seems that these conditions will always be met because every node will have a 'children' property, and it's value will always be an array. Is this done on purpose?

Comment: If you are sure these conditions will always be met sure: Kick the if-clause. It is just me looking from the outside who wants some more fail-safe code which will work if a node is missing the `children` property or if `children` is `null`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a generic function such:

```
const forEachNode = (callback, arrayLike) => 
  ([...arrayLike].forEach(value => {
    callback(value);
    if (typeof value.children === "object" && value.children.length > 0) {
     forEachNode(callback, value.children)
    }
  }));
```

At this point you could pass your `nodeArray` and the callback you want to execute for each of them (and their children), for example:

```
forEachNode(console.log, nodeArray);
```

You can also easily compose functions:

```
    const logAllNodes = forEachNode.bind(null, console.log);

    const countAllNodes = (nodes) => {
      let count = 0;
      forEachNode(() => count++, nodes);
      return count;
    }

    const flatten = (nodes) => {
      let acc = [];
      forEachNode(node => acc.push(node), nodes);
      return acc;
    }

    logAllNodes(nodeArray);
    console.log(countAllNodes(nodeArray));
    console.log(flatten(nodeArray));
```